# Finding average using Lambda (Double stored as String)

Tags: lambda, average, java-8

I have an object of the following format

```
Map<String, List<ObjectDTO>> mapOfIndicators = new HashMap<>();
```

ObjectDTO is

```
public class ObjectDTO {
 private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String iName;
    private String dName;
    private String countryName;
    private int year;

    //Since the value can be empty, using String instead of Double
    private String newIndex;
}
```

I am trying to compute the average of the newIndex value, which basically I cannot do as getNewIndex is String, and there can be empty string(values). I cannot convert to the null values to 0 as there will be 0 values in newIndex.

Is there an easier way to calculate the average?

Eg.

```
mapOfIndicators = new HashMap<>();
List<IndicatorTableDTO> _tempValue = new ArrayList();
IndicatorTableDTO _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName1", 2012, "1.00");
_tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
_iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName2", 2012, "");
_tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
_iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName3", 2012, "0.02");
_tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
_iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName4", 2012, "-0.25");
_tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
_iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName5", 2012, "0.10");
_tempValue.add(_iTDTO);

mapOfIndicators.put("Test1", _tempValue);

   _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName1", 2012, "0.10");
   _tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
   _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName2", 2012, "", "", "");
   _tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
   _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName3", 2012, "", "", "");
   _tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
   _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName4", 2012, "0.25", "", "");
   _tempValue.add(_iTDTO);
   _iTDTO = new IndicatorTableDTO("iName", "dName", "countryName5", 2012, "1.10", "", "");
   _tempValue.add(_iTDTO);

   mapOfIndicators.put("Test2", _tempValue);
```

Update 01: We can skip empty string/null values; the average would be per countryName, so I want to find the average of the newIndex for same contryName and eventually be able to get a Map as the final result.

Comment: You should include your conventional way of calculating to make your intentions more clear. Do you want an average per map entry or over the entire map, do you want to treat empty strings as 0 or skip them (which is not the same…)?

Comment: There is an easy way, as soon as you define what the average should be. If you don't know what the integer value should be when the string is empty, we can't either.

Comment: @Holger, Updated the question at the bottom

Comment: @Vivek: so the `countryName` is already the key of the map?

Comment: Yes, this of course would be a new map with just (CountryName, average)

Comment: @Vivek: my question was about the key of the *source* map and its relationship to the intended result. I’m asking because your last code example is inconsistent to the beginning of your question. The map you are constructing has a structure completely different from what you described.

Comment: @Hogler, you are right, I might have confused you with my previous answer, I have added a comment to your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but should do the trick (or at least guide you towards the solution):

```
Map<String, Double> averageByCountryName = 
    map.values()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
       .filter(objectDTO -> !objectDTO.getNewIndex().isEmpty())
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            ObjectDTO::getCountry,
            Collectors.averagingDouble(
                objectDTO -> Double.parseDouble(objectDTO.getNewIndex())));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the average of the values and collect them in a `Map` having the same keys as the source map, you can do it this way:

```
Map<String, Double> averages=mapOfIndicators.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e->e.getValue().stream()
       .map(ObjectDTO::getNewIndex).filter(str->!str.isEmpty())
       .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).average().orElse(Double.NaN)));
```

Since `ObjectDTO.newIndex` is declared `private`, I assumed that there is a method `getNewIndex` to get its value. I also provided the default value `Double.NaN` as behavior for the case that there are no non-empty `String`s in the value list which was not specified in the question.

---

In the case you want to average over a different key as with your question now defined more precisely, the code may look like:

```
Map<String, Double> averages=mapOfIndicators.values().stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(objectDTO -> !objectDTO.getNewIndex().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectDTO::getCountryName,
        Collectors.mapping(ObjectDTO::getNewIndex,
            Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble))));
```

Well, that’s similar to [JB Nizet’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851645/2711488) which got your intention right on the first guess…

Comment: Sorry if my previous note confused you. ObjectDTO has the countryName and not the Map from which we are trying to read, if you see the above example, the Key is 'Test1' & 'Test2'. We would need to create a new may with ObjectDTO.getCountryName() as key and Average of all the countryNames in the list; from Test1 and Test2.

Comment: thanks, your solution looks elegant as well. A quick question here, the the filter you have added here is checking is its not empty, is there a way I can ignore the entire country mapping if even one of them is newIndex for that country is empty?

Comment: @Vivek: that is not a “quick question” but an entirely new question. Asking new questions is not the intended scope of comments.

Comment: @Vivek: you may create a new question, you know…