# Java - Lambda filter criteria, to ignore adding to map

Tags: filter, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of the format (reference to [Finding average using Lambda (Double stored as String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851176))

```
Map<String, Double> averages=mapOfIndicators.values().stream()
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
.filter(objectDTO -> !objectDTO.getNewIndex().isEmpty())
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectDTO::getCountryName,
    Collectors.mapping(ObjectDTO::getNewIndex,
        Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble))));
```

I would like to ignore the ignore the entire country mapping even if one of them is newIndex value for that country is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Collectors.groupingBy` does not allow to skip groups, you either have to analyze the filtering condition in advance so you can filter before performing `groupBy` or filter the map afterwards (I ignore the third option, implement your own `groupingBy` collector.

1. Analyze in advance:

   ```
   Map<String, Boolean> hasEmpty=mapOfIndicators.values().stream()
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectDTO::getCountryName,
           Collectors.mapping(o->o.getNewIndex().isEmpty(),
               Collectors.reducing(false, Boolean::logicalOr))));
   Map<String, Double> averages=mapOfIndicators.values().stream()
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .filter(objectDTO -> !hasEmpty.get(objectDTO.getCountryName()))
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectDTO::getCountryName,
           Collectors.mapping(ObjectDTO::getNewIndex,
               Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::parseDouble))));
   ```
2. Filter the result:

   ```
   Map<String, Double> averages=mapOfIndicators.values().stream()
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectDTO::getCountryName,
               Collectors.mapping(ObjectDTO::getNewIndex, Collectors.averagingDouble(
                   s->s.isEmpty()? Double.NaN: Double.parseDouble(s)))),
           m->{ m.values().removeIf(d->Double.isNaN(d)); return m; }));
   ```